# Change background color of Selected Item of ComboBox in UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, combobox, desktop-application

I am new to XAML and UWP, I have a ComboBox in which I am using mentioned styles, Background color of selected item in list of all items is SkyBlue, I want to change it to Red or any other color,Can someone help me on how to do it?
Thanks in advance..

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="BorderElement.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="BorderElement.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentElement.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="BorderElement.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="BorderElement.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentElement.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="BorderElement.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="BorderElement.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentElement.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ContentElement.RequestedTheme" Value="Light"/>
                                            <Setter Target="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsTabStop="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,5,0,7"/>
            <Setter Property="MaxDropDownHeight" Value="504"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBoxStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <CarouselPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OverlayOpeningAnimation">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.383" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="1.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OverlayClosingAnimation">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.216" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="0.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundBorderBrushFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocused}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocusedPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForegroundFocusedPressed}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundFocusedPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditableModeStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocused">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <!--<Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}"/>-->
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocusedOverlayPointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <!--<Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}"/>-->
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxFocusedDropDownBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocusedOverlayPressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <!--<Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}"/>-->
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxFocusedDropDownBackgroundPointerPressed}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxOverlayPointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxOverlayPressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackgroundPointerPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxUnfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxTopHeaderMargin}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ComboBoxThemeMinWidth}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundUnfocused}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundBorderBrushUnfocused}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground}}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <TextBox x:Name="EditableText" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground}}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0,0,0,0" AutomationProperties.Name="{TemplateBinding AutomationProperties.Name}" Padding="10,3,30,5" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Load="False"/>
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownOverlay" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,2,2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="30" x:Load="False"/>
                            <!--<FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
                            <Path HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,10,10,10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 8 0 L 16 16 0 16 Z"
                              StrokeThickness="5"
                              StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                              Stroke="#FF1A428A"
                              Fill="#FF1A428A" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Description}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}" Grid.Row="2" x:Load="False"/>
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" CornerRadius="20" Background="White" BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge" BorderBrush="#FF1A428A" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-1,0,-1" Padding="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderPadding}">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}">
                                        </ItemsPresenter>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have tries some to do some changes in style but I don't have much idea how to do it.
If possible I dont want to use Triggers if it can be done with changes in style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wants to change the background color for the selected item, you need to change the style of the **ComboBoxItem**. Then assign the customized style to the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the **ComboBox** control.

Here is the style that you could directly use. Please find the `Background` brush in `Selected` `VisualState`. In the following code, I've changed it into **Red**. You could change it to other color that you want.

```
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" x:Key="MyItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealThemePadding}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="Red" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackgroundSelectedUnfocused}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedUnfocused}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedUnfocused}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackgroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealThemeTouchPadding}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemRevealThemeGameControllerPadding}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then you need to assign the style to the **ComboBox**

```
       <ComboBox x:Name="FontsCombo" 
             Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemStyle}" 
             Header="Fonts" Height="88" Width="296" 
             ItemsSource="{x:Bind fonts}" />
```